# React & TypeScript how pass data from child to parent at onClick via props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have parent and child component. And i wan't to pass from child to parent component data at onClick via props. How can i do that?  i tried:

**Parent.tsx**

```
const items = [
  {
    title: "A"
  },
  {
    title: "B"
  }
]

const Parent = () => {
   const [someState, setSomeState] = useState("");

   const toggleState = (e: React.MouseEvent, title: string) => {
     setSomeState(title);
   }

   return (
     <Child items={items} toggleState={(e) => toggleState(e, item.title)} />
   )
}
```

**Child.tsx**

```
type ChildProps = {
 items: Item[];
 toggleState: (e: React.MouseEvent) => void;
}

const Child: React.FC<ChildProps> = (props) => {
   return (
    {props.items.map((item) => (
       <button onClick={props.toggleState}> pass clicked item title to parent </button>
    ))}
   )
}
```

but in my parent component omn **toggleState** prop **item.title** showing error:

**any
Cannot find name 'item'.**

Comment: You don't pass any `items` to `Child`, and because you have strick any validation it throws an error.

Comment: Sorry i didn't show on example but actually i passed items to child

Answer (score 2):

As with any other function call, you have to pass the information as an argument:

`Parent.tsx`:

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [someState, setSomeState] = useState("");

   const toggleState = (e: React.MouseEvent, title: string) => {
     setSomeState(title);
   }

   return (
     <Child toggleState={(e, title) => toggleState(e, title)} items={items}/>
   )
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
}
```

`Child.tsx`:

```
type ChildProps = {
 items: Item[];
 toggleState: (e: React.MouseEvent, title: string) => void;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

const Child: React.FC<ChildProps> = (props) => {
   return (
    {props.items.map((item) => (
       <button onClick={(e) => props.toggleState(e, item.title)}> pass clicked item title to parent </button>
    ))}
   )
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Note the changes to `toggleState` in `Parent.tsx` and `onClick` in `Child.tsx`.

Live Example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

/*
interface Item {
  title: string;
}
*/
const items = [
    {title: "Item 1"},
    {title: "Item 2"},
    {title: "Item 3"},
    {title: "Item 4"},
];

const Parent = () => {
   const [someState, setSomeState] = useState("");

   const toggleState = (e/*: React.MouseEvent*/, title/*: string*/) => {
     setSomeState(title);
   }

   return (
     <div>
       <div>someState = {someState}</div>
       <Child items={items} toggleState={(e, title) => toggleState(e, title)} />
     </div>
   )
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
}

/*
type ChildProps = {
 items: Item[];
 toggleState: (e: React.MouseEvent, title: string) => void;
}
*/

const Child/*: React.FC<ChildProps>*/ = (props) => {
   return <React.Fragment>
    {props.items.map((item) => (
       <button onClick={(e) => props.toggleState(e, item.title)}> pass clicked item title to parent </button>
    ))}
   </React.Fragment>
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-GZvswrJK4M8IMA0bYGLs4B72bGZNcAGKMlFlr0+1B9KTtMCNnMA3Sw+GIlFxm5VqDIKxExTqmJtiC+6581DXEDIMDtdp8nPtBkogBGXBg+0RLEZhmAuAA1qKsDnJ9OI7KsJM+dcIaI+mA0OhcEfT1gOXz5f49BAcCvi08A0tuu4sOOcCdJ0djeDS-bVkOI4puO2p6naxrWlamFGth+EOnYQA) to show the types work.

Comment: if i tried this getting error in child : (property) title: string
Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.   and in parent : Type '(e: any, title: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => void'.ts(2322)

Comment: @ciz30 - Just a typo-level error, `title` was missing from `toggleState` in `ChildProps`. I've fixed that and added a runnable example and a link to the playground.